# Error control/handler (capture) with Behavior in wcf. Business layer

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, error-handling, behavior

I have a project (backend) where it receives a call in the service layer, but it also makes calls to another API in the business layer.

I have added a behaviour to those calls so I do not have to make changes to several places in my code.

My Behaviour.config (the importatn is ExternalDependencyBehavior):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- SPECIFIC BEHAVIOR EXTENSION FOR JSON URL DESERIALIZER-->
    <behavior name="ServiceRESTBehavior">
      <ConverterWebHttpBehaviourExtension />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ServiceSOAPBehavior" />
    <behavior name="ExternalDependencyBehavior">
      <ExternalClientBehavior/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>  
</behaviors>
```

My code: (one method in business layer that call a other API external)

```cs
protected virtual Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.RespuestaSNPV1201 RequestToVendor(VendorWebService vendor, string clientFiscalId, BasicSearchCriterion criteria)
{
    Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.RespuestaSNPV1201 result = new Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.RespuestaSNPV1201();
    string errorLogProvider = null;

    try
    {
       using (Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.SNPV1201SoapClient client = new Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.SNPV1201SoapClient())
       {
        /*Credentials*/
        result = client.ConsultaRutificacion(
                client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName,
                client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password,
                clientFiscalId,
                criteria.Value
            );
        }
    return result;
    }
    catch (AxrException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (FaultException fex)
    {
        this.logProvider.WriteInErrorMode(GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, fex);
        throw this.exceptionProvider.Create(ErrorCode.---------, ExceptionType.BUSINESS, fex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logProvider.WriteInErrorMode(GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
        throw this.exceptionProvider.Create(ErrorCode.-------------, ExceptionType.BUSINESS, ex);
    }
}
```

In summary:

When I arrive at the call:
"client.ConsultaRutification"

My behaviour is executed, I add the code (2 files):

```cs
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace SIPE.Search.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements methods that can be used to extend run-time behavior for an endpoint in either a client application.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExternalClientBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new ExternalClientBehaviorClass();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(ExternalClientBehaviorClass);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// JSON REST[GET] Converter Behavior
        /// </summary>
        private class ExternalClientBehaviorClass : IEndpointBehavior
        {
            public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {                
            }

            public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
            {
                ExternalClientMessageInspector clientInspector = new ExternalClientMessageInspector(endpoint);
                clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(clientInspector);

                foreach (ClientOperation op in clientRuntime.Operations)
                {
                    op.ParameterInspectors.Add(clientInspector);
                }
            }

            public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
            {
                endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ExternalClientMessageInspector(endpoint));
            }

            public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

And file two:

```cs
namespace SIPE.Search.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Intercepts send requests. 
    /// </summary>
    public class ExternalClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IParameterInspector, IErrorHandler
    {
        private ServiceEndpoint Endpoint { get; set; }

        Dictionary<string, object> inputsParam;

        public ExternalClientMessageInspector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            //empty
        }

        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
            ((Dictionary<string, string>)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items[operationName])).Add("OutputParam", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnValue));

        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            //code not necessary
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            // code not neccesary
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            Message copy = buffer.CreateMessage();  // Create a copy to work with
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();         // Restore the original message

            return copy.GetReaderAtBodyContents().Name;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            // no implement
        }

        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            // no implement
            return true;
        }

        public void NotifyError()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**I need to be able to capture the errors, (for example 404 and others) of my calls within my behaviour.
I have tried to add several interfaces, but without success**

The error is captured by the catch of the RequestToVendor method that is in the business layer.
But I need to be able to capture it in my behaviour.

thank you

Comment: Ok, so I'm gonna link you to the [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help page and ask you to focus on minimal. This is wayyy too much code. Most people will come here, see the amount of code and leave again without bothering to even try and help

Comment: Yes i understand
But I think I can not sum up the problem enough to explain what I want.

I will try it in a few days if there is no answer.
Thank you

I will try it in a few days if there is no answer.
Thank you

Comment: delete code not necessary for simplify

Comment: in config you call it ExternalDependencyBehavior and in code ExternalClientBehavior have you read this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions/

Comment: it is not problem.... forget config file